# If statement is skipping the first user input scanner object

Tags: if-statement, java.util.scanner

Program segment works ok but is skipping the first task in the if statement.

The output is as follows if user has selected "Y"

> Do you wish to add another subject code  - Y or N?
>   y
>
> Enter the subject name:
>   Enter subject code:
>
> abc123

It is not giving the user the chance to enter the subject name.  It worked before creating the if statement, so I am assuming it has something to do with that.  I have been wracking my brain but to no avail.

```
 System.out.println("Do you wish to add another subject code  - Y or N?  ");
    String response = input.next();

    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

    /**User input*/

    System.out.println("\nEnter the subject name: ");
    String subjectName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nEnter subject code: ");
    String subjectCode = input.next();
    Subject mySubject = new Subject(subjectCode, subjectName);

    /**Write to the file*/
    output.println(mySubject.getSubjectCode() + " " + mySubject.getSubjectName());
    output.close();
    }
    else  
      output.close();

    System.out.println("\nProgram terminated\n");
```

Cheers,
Susan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String response = input.next();     // Wrong
String response = input.nextLine(); // Right
```

When you do `input.next()`, you just read the first word of the line.

When you afterwards do `input.nextLine()`, you read up until the next line feed.

That means that if you type `y<enter>`, the first statement will read `y` and the second statement will read up until the `<enter>` which is just the empty string.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your explanation of next() and nextLine() is excellent.